# QColorDialog and QItemDelegate

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a QTableView and I'm Using a QItemDelegate in it as button. 
I'm trying to change the color of the button, so when i click on it i call a QColorDialog. But then I'm having trouble sending the color it back to the button.

Here's how it is going so far:

the Button and QColorDialog:

```
class ButtonDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        btn = QPushButton('')
        btn.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(86,12,65)")
        ix = QPersistentModelIndex(index)
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda ix = ix : self.onClicked(ix))
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        layout.setContentsMargins(2,2,2,2)
        if not self.parent().indexWidget(index):
            self.parent().setIndexWidget(index, widget)

    def onClicked(self, ix):

        colorPicker = QColorDialog.getColor()
        #colorPicker.show()
        r = str(colorPicker.red())
        g = str(colorPicker.red())
        b = str(colorPicker.red())
        bgcolor = 'background-color:rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b +')'
```

What's the next step? I tried declaring the button in the delegate **init** as `self.btn = QPushButton()` and then reuse it at the onCLick Method, but the button don't even get drawn that way.

Some enlightenment?

Thank you!

edit 1

Model:

```
class Model(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, vtxTable, parent = None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        #data
        self.groups = []
        #header
        self.header_labels = ['Color', 'Group', 'Done']
        self.vtxTable = vtxTable


    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.groups)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 3

    def flags(self, index):

        if index.column() == 2: 
            fl = fl = Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        else:
            fl = Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return fl


    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.header_labels[section]

    def removeRow(self, row, parent = QModelIndex()):
        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row)
        self.groups.remove(self.groups[row])
        self.endRemoveRows()
        self.vtxTable.setModel(QStringListModel())


    def insertRows(self, position, row, values = [] , parent = QModelIndex()):

        lastposition = self.rowCount(0)
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, lastposition, lastposition)
        self.groups.insert(lastposition, values)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def setData(self, index, value, role = Qt.EditRole):

        setIt = False
        value = value
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()

        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            setIt = True

            if not len(value) == 0: 
                if value in self.getGrpNames():
                    warning("Group must have a unique name.")
                    setIt = False
                else:
                    setIt = True
            else:
                warning("New group must have a name.")
                setIt = False

        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            setIt = True

        if setIt:
            self.groups[row][column] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(row, column)

        return False

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return 

        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if column == 0: 
                #value = [self.groups[row][column].redF(), self.groups[row][column].greenF(), self.groups[row][column].blueF()]
                value = self.groups[row][column]
            else:
                value = self.groups[row][column]
            return value

        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignCenter;

        elif role == Qt.EditRole: 
            index = index 
            return index.data()   

        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole and column == 0:
            value = self.groups[row][column]


    def getGrpNames(self):
        rows = self.rowCount(1)
        grps = []
        for row in range(rows):
            grp = self.index(row, 1).data()
            grps.append(grp)

        return grps

    def getAllVtx(self):

        rows = self.rowCount(1)
        allVtxs = []
        for row in range(rows):
            index =  self.createIndex(row, 3)
            vtxs = index.data()
            for vtx in vtxs:
                allVtxs.append(vtx)
        return allVtxs

    def getData(self):
        rows = self.rowCount(1)
        data = {}
        for row in range(rows):
            color = self.index(row, 0).data()
            grp = self.index(row, 1).data()
            done = self.index(row, 2).data()
            vtxs = self.groups[row][3]
            #index = self.createIndex(row,0)
            data[grp] = [grp, color, done, vtxs]

        return data

    def queryVtx(self, vtx):

        data = self.getData()

        for key in data:
            vtxs = data[key][3]
            if vtx in vtxs:
                return data[key][0]

        else:
            return False
```

Table View:

```
class Table(QTableView):

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        QTableView.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, colorDelegate(self))
        hHeader = self.horizontalHeader()
        #hHeader.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Fixed);
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        vHeader = self.verticalHeader()
        vHeader.hide()
```

[image: When clicking on the cell i'd like to select the custom color, display it there, and set the data.]

When clicking on the first cell of the row I'd like to be able top pick a color for it, and save it in the model.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to use a button?

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the cell or do you want to change only the color name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of the delegates is to customize each item that is displayed in a QAbstractItemView, the other way to do it is by inserting a widget using the indexWidget method. The advantage of the delegates is that the memory consumption is minimal. It is advisable not to use them at the same time.

The delegates have the following methods:

- `paint()`: is the method responsible for drawing the item that is normally displayed
- `createEditor()`: is the method is responsible for creating the editor.
- `setEditorData()`: get the value of the model and establish it in the editor.
- `setModelData()`: save the data obtained from the editor to the model.

An example of that type of delegate is the following:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *


class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        dialog = QColorDialog(parent)
        return dialog

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        color = index.data(Qt.BackgroundRole)
        editor.setCurrentColor(color)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        color = editor.currentColor()
        model.setData(index, color, Qt.BackgroundRole)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QStandardItemModel(4, 4)
    for i in range(model.rowCount()):
        for j in range(model.columnCount()):
            color = QColor(qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256)
            it = QStandardItem("{}{}".format(i, j))
            it.setData(color, Qt.BackgroundRole)
            model.setItem(i, j, it)
    w = QTableView()
    w.setModel(model)
    w.setItemDelegate(Delegate())
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Update:

I have improved your code since it had unnecessary elements, the main error is that these `Qt::BackgroundRole` must return a QColor

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

import warnings

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        #data
        self.groups = []
        #header
        self.header_labels = ['Color', 'Group', 'Done']


    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.groups)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def flags(self, index):
        fl = Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        if not index.column() in (2, ):
            fl |= Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return fl


    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.header_labels[section]

    def removeRow(self, row, parent = QModelIndex()):
        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row)
        self.groups.remove(self.groups[row])
        self.endRemoveRows()

    def insertRows(self, values = [], position=-1):
        if position == -1:
            position = self.rowCount()
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), position, position)
        self.groups.insert(position, values)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def setData(self, index, value, role = Qt.EditRole):
        setIt = False
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            setIt = True
            if len(value) != 0: 
                if value in self.getGrpNames():
                    warning("Group must have a unique name.")
                    setIt = False
                else:
                    setIt = True
            else:
                warning("New group must have a name.")
                setIt = False
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            setIt = True
        if setIt:
            self.groups[row][column] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)

        return False

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return 

        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()

        value = None

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if column == 0:
                value = self.groups[row][column]
            else:
                value = self.groups[row][column]
        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            value = Qt.AlignCenter;  
        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole and column == 0:
            value = QColor(self.groups[row][column])
        return value

    def getGrpNames(self):
        rows = self.rowCount(1)
        grps = []
        for row in range(rows):
            grp = self.index(row, 1).data()
            grps.append(grp)
        return grps

    def getAllVtx(self):
        rows = self.rowCount(1)
        allVtxs = []
        for row in range(rows):
            index =  self.createIndex(row, 3)
            vtxs = index.data()
            for vtx in vtxs:
                allVtxs.append(vtx)
        return allVtxs

    def getData(self):
        rows = self.rowCount(1)
        data = {}
        for row in range(rows):
            color = self.index(row, 0).data()
            grp = self.index(row, 1).data()
            done = self.index(row, 2).data()
            vtxs = self.groups[row][3]
            #index = self.createIndex(row,0)
            data[grp] = [grp, color, done, vtxs]
        return data

    def queryVtx(self, vtx):
        data = self.getData()
        for key in data:
            vtxs = data[key][3]
            if vtx in vtxs:
                return data[key][0]
        else:
            return False

class ColorDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        dialog = QColorDialog(parent)
        return dialog

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        color = index.data(Qt.BackgroundRole)
        editor.setCurrentColor(color)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        color = editor.currentColor()
        model.setData(index, color, Qt.BackgroundRole)

class Table(QTableView):
    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        QTableView.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, ColorDelegate(self))
        hHeader = self.horizontalHeader()
        #hHeader.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Fixed);
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        vHeader = self.verticalHeader()
        vHeader.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Table()
    model = Model()
    w.setModel(model)
    model.insertRows(["red", "group1", "no"])
    model.insertRows(["blue", "group1", "no"], 0)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. Learning to code has been quite a ride, and for those not initiated it is often a obscure ride. Thank you for your well rounded answers.

Comment: I tried to adapt the code but i'm bumping into some trouble: I'm not using a QStandardItemModel but a QAbstractTableModel.... the setModelData, I believe, is not working properly...also, the color does no show.... I'm messing around with it, but i believe the issue is the different kind o model being used.... thoughts?

Comment: So far I defined the Delegate as in your answer, at the QTableView I set the delegate  `code`[self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, colorDelegate(self))]   and at the data method my QTableModel I set `code`[if role = Qt.DisplayRole and column == 0: return model.data[row, column] ##this is a QColor]...  I get the color written in the cell.. but not as the delegate....  also, the color picker shows up but does not change the color...  back to the documentation.

Comment: Ok, the setData I fixed... simple thing. I forgot to add the if role == Qt.BackgroundRole in the model setdata...  my bad. now trying to fix the color display.

Comment: Do you want to use the model of your previous question? I saw that your model had the name of the color in the first column. Do you want to use those values?

Comment: Yes!  Would you like to see some specific part of the code?

Comment: There are colors that do not have names, so what do you want to happen when the color is changed?

Comment: Add that code to your question and show me an image of what you want to get after changing to an unknown color. Do you want me to put the name in hexadecimal?

Comment: will do in a minute. Thank you

Comment: Just editted. but... i'm sorry, i think I editted your answer, not my question.. I apologize...

Comment: Sorry. my mistake.

Comment: OK thank you for the help!! Very much appreciated. and sorry for editing wrongly.